# Number of functions with one element in the range when continuously composed

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question that goes:

Find the number of functions $f: X \to X$, such that the range of the $n$ times composed function $f^{(n)}$ has only one element. Given that $|X| = n$, where $|X|$ is the number of the elements in $X$.

It is obvious that when $n = 1, 2$, the number of those functions are $1, 2$. I observed by python that if $n \le 8 $, the number of those functions are $n^{n-1}$.

I tried to solve the question by counting "functions without a loop", where a loop is defined as a subset of $X$ $L$ such that $f(L) = L$. If the function as one or more loop (in the case of loops with size $1$, more than one), no matter how many times composed, its range will never have one element.

The number of loops with size $n$ is $(n-1)!$. If the number of loops with size $n$ is $a_n$ , $a_{n+1 }=n a_n$, so $a_n = (n-1)!$

From now on, I am stuck on how to solve the original problem. Could anybody help?

Comment: $f^{(n)}$ is a strange notation for an $m$-times composition. And what does $n(X)$ mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If there is a better way, please let me know. $n(X)$ means the number of elements in $X$. I've added in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, try using OEIS. Maybe https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+9%2C+64%2C+&language=english&go=Search will give you a hint... cheers

Comment: I think you know what the problem was, John, as you edited to correct it.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that this count will depend only on $n$, not on $m$. That seems unrealistic. I’m wondering whether $m$ is supposed to be $n$?

Comment: @joriki I just made an edit to make this a whole lot clearer, I think. I believe I am respecting the John P's intentions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest You made the question look simpler! I found out that I would need no more than $n$ times of composition would be needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that functions $f:X\to X$, for which the range of $f^{(n)}(x)$ has exactly one element, are in bijection with labeled rooted trees on the vertex set $X$. In this correspondence, the root vertex is the unique element $x$ of $X$ which is a fixed point of $f$, meaning $f(x)=x$.

Then, apply [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Labeled_trees), which says that the number of labeled *unrooted* trees on $n$ vertices is $n^{n-2}$. Then, a labeled rooted tree is given by choosing a tree in $n^{n-2}$ ways, and choosing one of $n$ elements of $X$ to be a root, so the number of rooted labeled trees is $n\cdot n^{n-2}=n^{n-1}$.

Comment: Is the term "tree" in graph theory? I'll look up for that term. Thanks for the answer!